# Which style of these two is more explicit (pythonic)?

Tags: python, styles

This is the slice of code I wrote:

```
if player_a in reward_dict:
    reward_dict[player] += money
elif player_a not in reward_dict:
    reward_dict[player] = money
```

I wrote like this, because I think it is easy to read, you need not do any logic conclusions to get the meaning straightforward.

But my colleague saw my code, and he said: "That's not explicit, becuase player_a has only 2 possibilities, in a dict or not."

So, according to his opinion, this code should be write like this:

```
if player_a in reward_dict:
    reward_dict[player] += money
else:
    reward_dict[player] = money
```

I feel hard to judge between these two styles, so I asked this question, and hope the opinions of more people would make it clear.

What's your opinion about these two styles?

Comment: Just for the record, the most pythonic solution would be to use either a `collections.defaultdict`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if player_a in reward_dict:
    reward_dict[player] += money
else:
    reward_dict[player] = money
```

In my opinion, this is the appropriate one. We will normally go for 'elif' if we have more than two conditions to check for. Otherwise else is the best way to put in though both are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is more explicit concerning the exact meaning of the word explicit, but the point of your colleague is right, because there are really only 2 possibilities: 'in' or 'not in'. So the second block would be more elegant (readable, comprehensive) in my opinion.
The first block should be used when there are more than 2 possibilities. Just my two cents.